# Rhino Javascript - how to label a string source for exception stacktrace

Tags: javascript, java, exception, rhino

We use Rhino Javascript (JDK7 interpreted Mode), with heavy use of "eval" both from the ScriptEngine.eval(String) and within javascript using eval(String).  We recognize there may be security concerns with eval... but that aside...

When an exception is thrown, it is eventually caught by java, the java stacktrace prints out something like: (#7) in  at line number 7.

It makes sense that the source's name is unknown, because we just gave it a string to eval.

However, is there any way to attach a label to a given eval, so that it will provide better hints in the stacktrace?  Something like:

```
String jsCode = "va z=x+y".....
eval(jsCode, "label1");
```

So that when the exception is thrown it would say something like : ( Label1) in  at line number 7.

This would make it easier to debug and find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crate simple wrapper on JS eval function:

```
function evalWithLabel(js, label) {
    try {
        return eval(js);
    } catch(err) {
        throw label + ': ' + err;
    }
}
```